# How to ignore nan values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to check if my last close is higher (or lower) then the support or resistince an my dataframe.
The problem is that i have a lot of nan values. How can i ignore those values and just check the last integer value of the colum? below just a short line of code to check if the close is below the support.
I have added an picture of my dataframe.

```
df["Close"][-1] < df["Support"][1] and df["Open"][1] < df["Support"][1]:
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`dropna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) before indexing with `iloc`:

```py
close_condition = df["Close"].dropna().iloc[-1] < df["Support"].dropna().iloc[0]
open_condition = df["Open"].dropna().iloc[0] < df["Support"].dropna().iloc[0]

if close_condition and open_condition:
    ...
```

Comment: One more question. Why the use of .iloc[0] and not just [0]?

Comment: In your case it looks like the index is `Date`, so this wouldn't be relevant. If the index were the default numerical range and index 0 happened to be `nan`, then `dropna()` would drop the 0th index and `[0]` would throw an error (but `iloc[0]` would still work).